# Custom Block - save.js function not saving attributes

Tags: javascript, block-editor, validation

I'm trying to get just a basic custom block displaying in the editor and saving. I've followed multiple tutorials and I keep getting the same result. No matter how simple my block is, whenever I add a saved attribute, I can no longer save the page that contains the block. I get a block validation error. **I know the save.js function is not saving** the attributes correctly, I just don't know why. Here's my block.json attribute section:

```
    "attributes": {
      "content": {
        "type": "string",
        "source": "text",
        "selector": "p"
      }
    },
```

I'm using just a single RichText field in my edit.js:

```
 import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
 import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
 import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
 import './styles/editor.scss';
 
 export default function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    const onChangeContent = ( newContent ) => {
        setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
    }

    return (
        <RichText 
            { ...blockProps }
            tagName="p"
            onChange={ onChangeContent }
            allowedFormats={ [ 'core/bold', 'core/italic' ] }
            value={ attributes.content }
            placeholder={ __( 'Write your text...' ) }
        />
    );
}
```

And finally, here is my save function:

```
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
 
export default function save( { attributes } ) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
    return (
        <RichText.Content
            {...blockProps}
            tagName="p"
            value={ attributes.content }
        />
    );
}
```

The error I get after saving is:

```
Content generated by `save` function:

<p class="wp-block-kateandco-kate-block"></p>

Content retrieved from post body:

<p class="wp-block-kateandco-kate-block">my inner text, saved as p</p>
```

Comment: Any luck to solving this?

Comment: Aa I can see, you are not saving anything in the save function.
And you're not supposed to. The save function does not store JavaScript code.